# iterating though an element using format method

Tags: python, class

Here is my simplified code as i can't post my actual code in python 3:

```
class example(object):
    def __init__(self, list1):
        self.list1 = list1
    def __repr__(self):
        if len(self.list1) > 0:
            for i in self.list1:
                for j in range(1,len(self.list1)):
                    return ('{0:}{1:}').format(j, i)

x = example(['this', 'is', 'a', 'list'])
x
```

This should return:

```
1this
```

Now im wanting it to return:

```
1this
2is
3a
4list
```

How do i go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Just use `enumerate` function as follows:

```
class example(object):
    def __init__(self, list1):
        self.list1 = list1
    def __repr__(self):
        return '\n'.join('{0}{1}'.format(c+1, el) for c, el in enumerate(self.list1))
```

Comment: better: return '\n'.join('{0}{1}'.format(c, el) for c, el in enumerate(self.list1,1))

Comment: I prefer `enumerate` to be always be zero-based and add the offset myself. I dont think `c+1` has any perfomance penalty of significance. And `c+1` is self explanatory.